# cant figure out why there is error in my CMD while creating server with nodeJs

Tags: node.js, cmd

[This is the NodeJs code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XmvF.png)

[This is the error in CMD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fz2Aw.png)

Comment: Can't figure out what you are asking! Don't post links to some images, post a proper question! Regard that links might break in future, so this post is completely useless then...

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access myRequest.url which is only declared not defined. (So it doesn't have a url property which you could access).

I think you should use the parameter req instead, thats the request your server is handling.

It should be:

```
http.createServer(function(req,res){
    var myRequest = req;
```

and the rest of the code should work.

Comment: still the image on the port is not displaying